# How do I rotate the screen at BOOT time (GUI is rotated but boot messages are still upside down)?

Tags: display

I'm using an LCD module, and I've set `display_rotate=2` in my `/boot/config.txt, however when the pi boots, it still shows boot messages upside down. Once the gui boots it is right-side-up. This isn't a deal breaker or anything, but I would like to be able to read the boot messages if needed.

Using Raspberry Pi 4 Model B

The LCD display is [Waveshare 3.5inch (A)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00OZLG2YS)

I'm using the [Octopi](https://octoprint.org/download/) variant of Raspbian.

Comment: Can you remove "display_rotate=2" in your "/boot/config.txt" and rotate the display 180 degrees.

Comment: What Pi? What OS? What display?

Comment: If using Grub, try adding `fbcon=rotate:3` to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX of `/etc/default/grub`.  The same might work in `/boot/cmdline.txt` but I am not certain

Comment: @Gil not sure if that's sarcasm or not. Obviously I cannot physically rotate the display due to the way it is mounted on the pi. The pi itself is mounted on another enclosure in a specific orientation.

Comment: @Milliways it's raspian, the screen is a [Waveshare 3.5 inch display](https://www.amazon.com/Waveshare-Raspberry-Resistive-Interface-Rapsberry-pi/dp/B00OZLG2YS)

Comment: Sorry I could not see it and your description and link to the module did not show on my screen.

Comment: DO NOT put detail in Comments - edit your Question. "it's raspian" No such thing Raspbian is a generic family of OS with considerable variation. If you want Answers you have to supply details.

Comment: @Milliways fair enough, I've updated the post with details on pi model and specific OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to add the following to `/boot/cmdline.txt`:

```
fbcon=rotate:2
```

Thanks [@bjornruffians](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/232287)